# changing navigation bar breakpoint in bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

im making an navigation bar but when im setting the font size higher of my list it does not collapse good so i wanted to change the breakpoint. I saw many answers how to fix it but none of it worked so im asking if you guys know how i can fix this?

Comment: You'll probably need to overwrite the standard media querie boundaries of bootstrap. I suggest reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149896/how-can-i-overwrite-media-queries-defined-in-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and easiest way would be to compile and download a custom Bootstrap CSS file by going to the [Customize and download page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) from Bootstrap, adjusting the breakpoints of the media queries and finally clicking the button at the bottom of the page 'Compile and download'. It should be working for any version of bootstrap as far as I know.
Hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: @Choori02 You might need to clear your browser's cache before the changes take effect. (Make sure to rename the new stylesheet over the old one, and read the source to make sure the breakpoints have changed.) And, if Kevin's answer works for you, make sure to mark it as accepted.